# How can I translate this python lasso regression code into Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to use some lasso regression python code from a third party in an existing Matlab-based application, although I'm having trouble figuring out the most equivalent Matlab functions to use. I also don't have a strong enough background in regression models to know how to check for parity.

The goal is to fit the 'z_ref' signal (a 1D pandas data frame) to the 'z_signal' signal (the same dimension/size).

Here is the original python code I'd like to convert:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
lin = Lasso(alpha=0.0001,precompute=True,max_iter=1000,
            positive=True, random_state=9999, selection='random')
lin.fit(z_ref, z_signal)
z_ref_fitted = lin.predict(z_ref).reshape(len(z_ref),1)
```

And here is my first attempt at equivalent Matlab code:

```matlab
[B,fitInfo] = lasso(z_ref,z_signal,'Alpha',0.0001,'MaxIter',1000);
coeff = B(1);
intercept = fitInfo.Intercept(1);
z_ref_fitted = z_ref * coeff + intercept;
```

The main thing I'm not sure about is what the python Lasso and .fit() implementation, of the sklearn package, is actually doing. From this python code the 'lin' object appears to get a single intercept and coef value, e.g.:

```py
lin.intercept_
Out[33]: array([0.2758512])

lin.coef_
Out[34]: array([0.04887462])
```

However, in Matlab, my code above produces, for example, B as a 1x100 double array, and a 'fitInfo' struct as follows:

```matlab
 struct with fields:

         Intercept: [1×100 double]
            Lambda: [1×100 double]
             Alpha: 1.0000e-04
                DF: [1×100 double]
               MSE: [1×100 double]
    PredictorNames: {}
```

So in a simple sense I'm not sure what coef and intercept values I should be using from the matlab implementation. In my attempted code above I'm using the first in each array, which gives a fairly similar outcome to the Python code (the z_ref_fitted output looks similar, but smaller).

Any guidance on a better Matlab implementation of the python code, or theoretical things I should look into would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha that you set for Lasso() in Python code is for regularization parameters.
The alpha that you set for lasso() in matlab code is for weight of lasso versus ridge optimization.
Since you didn't set regularization parameters in matlab lasso(), so by default, lasso performs lasso regularization using a geometric sequence of Lambda values, the results in 100 columns vector which each columns are results corresponding to each Lambda values

You should change your matlab code like this
[B,fitInfo] = lasso(z_ref,z_signal,'Lambda',0.0001,'MaxIter',1000);

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks Forte! That seems to make the outcome more comparable. I'll have to look into it further to make sure

Comment: It's my pleasure. Happy coding!